# why this static attribute is null?

Tags: apex

Given the following class:

```java
public without sharing class IncidentMigrationHelper {
    static final Map<SObjectField, SObjectField> CASE_FIELDS_BY_INCIDENT_FIELD
       = new Map<SObjectField, SObjectField>{
           Incident.Account_Name__c => Case.Account_Name__c,
           Incident.AccountId__c => Case.AccountId,
           Incident.AccountInformation__c => Case.AccountInformation__c
       };

    public static List<SObjectField> allIncidentFields() {
        return new List<SObjectField>(CASE_FIELDS_BY_INCIDENT_FIELD.keySet());
    }
}
```

When I execute the code below from an Anonymous Window or from a Unit test class:

```java
System.debug(IncidentMigrationHelper.allIncidentFields());
```

I get the following error:

```shell
FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

Investigating the code I learned the problem is happening because `CASE_FIELDS_BY_INCIDENT_FIELD` is null when I call `allIncidentFields()` method.

According to my (flaw) apex knowledge, the static `CASE_FIELDS_BY_INCIDENT_FIELD` should be initialized at the moment `allIncidentFields()` retrieves its value.

Can somebody help me to learn what I am missing here?

**UPDATE: A version of the class truly reproducing the problem:**

```java
public with sharing class TempClass {
    public static List<SObjectField> allIncidentFields() {
        return new List<SObjectField>(CASE_FIELDS_BY_INCIDENT_FIELD.keySet());
    }

    static final Map<SObjectField, SObjectField> CASE_FIELDS_BY_INCIDENT_FIELD
       = new Map<SObjectField, SObjectField>{
           Incident.Account_Name__c => Case.Account_Name__c,
           Incident.AccountId__c => Case.AccountId,
           Incident.AccountInformation__c => Case.AccountInformation__c
       };

    public static SObjectField getCaseFieldForIncidentField(
        SObjectField incidentField
    ) {
        return CASE_FIELDS_BY_INCIDENT_FIELD.get(incidentField);
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue cannot be because of above code. Please share full class to determine the issue.

Comment: You're correct. Something else in the class is preventing this attribute from being initialized.

Comment: It is good to narrow code down to what you suspect is the root cause when posting here, but it does indeed seem certain you have made a mistake in your investigation.

Comment: As a general principal, all static variables and static blocks gets called when the moment you call `IncidentMigrationHelper `, so you can share all static variables and blocks in your code, or investigate on these pointers

Comment: Please include a stack trace indicating _exactly_ which line threw the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that static variables are initialized in source order. That means that if you try to initialize them out of order with methods, you can end up with that situation.

```
public class X {
  public static Integer getXPlus2() {
    // Null pointer exception...
    return counter + 2;
  }
  public static Integer xPlus2 = getXPlus2();
  public static counter = 0;
}
```

---

```
public class X {
  public static Integer getXPlus2() {
    // Return 2
    return counter + 2;
  }
  public static counter = 0;
  public static Integer xPlus2 = getXPlus2();
}
```

This can get even more complicated when you have multiple classes that do this. You need to pay close attention to the source code order. It's strongly recommended that you put any static initializers that call static methods as the very last few lines of code to avoid this condition:

```
public class X {
  public static Integer getXPlus2() {
    // Return 2
    return counter + 2;
  }
  public static counter;
  public static Integer xPlus2;
  static {
    counter = 0;
    xPlus2 = getXPlus2();
  }
}
```

This way, it should be more obvious as to what's being assigned at what time. Static blocks also execute in source order, thus, the advice to put them at the end.

Comment: you're correct: I was somehow aware of the influence of the order of static members. The method I was calling (`getCaseFieldForIncidentField`) is after the const `CASE_FIELDS_BY_INCIDENT_FIELD` but I had another member (`allIncidentFields`) declared *before* the const. When `getCaseFieldForIncidentField` is invoked, all static members are initialized in the order they are declared in the file and at the initialization of `allIncidentFields` the const hasn't been initialized yet. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning that in list simply return keyset.If it not working show me how you are initializing map.

```
public without sharing class IncidentMigrationHelper {
    public Map<SObjectField, SObjectField> CASE_FIELDS_BY_INCIDENT_FIELD
       = new Map<SObjectField, SObjectField>{ /* few elements here */ };

    public static List<SObjectField> allIncidentFields() {
        return CASE_FIELDS_BY_INCIDENT_FIELD.keySet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It haven't worked. I have updated the post to include the map initialization.

Comment: Where is Incident.Account_Name__c and Case.Account_Name__c defined? If it is string put it in quotes

Comment: Those are field tokens, a perfectly valid way of statically referencing fields in a map like this.

Comment: There could be a good reason to convert it into a list (e.g. to prevent the caller from messing with the data since lists, sets and maps are mutable). Additionally you have return type list but try to return a set.